# ElasticSearch don't penalise verbose content

Tags: elasticsearch

We're using ElasticSearch to return recipes from our database.

Our problem is that ElasticSearch penalises verbose content:

For a search term like "Chicken Pasta", the ranking would come out as: 
1. "Chicken Pasta"
2. "Tasty Chicken Pasta"

Further,
1. "Horrible Chicken Pasta"
2. "Very Tasty Chicken Pasta"

For our domain, within certain parts of recipes, we don't want to penalise verbose content. I.e. many ingredients should be, within certain constraints, just as good as just a few ingredients.

I'd really appreciate some advice on how we could solve this issue.

Nick

Comment: you can play with the indexing of fields. this is an example from our codebase `name_sort: { type: "string", index: "not_analyzed", omit_norms: true, omit_term_freq_and_positions: true, include_in_all: false }`

Comment: here is a nice explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222652/elasticsearch-when-to-set-omit-norms-option-as-false

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom scoring functions to calculate the score of the results yourself. Here is a great webcast explaining custom scoring functions:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/videos/introducing-custom-scoring-functions/

The query that you have to use is the:

```
function_score
```

query to provide your own scoring. You'll find the most important information about the function_score query in the following document:

```
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html
```